# Add computer to home group on Windows 7

Tags: homegroup

I have created a homegroup in one laptop and I would like to add another laptop to this homegroup.
But it isn't displayed any homegroup where I can add the other laptop.

Both operating systems are Windows 7 and both laptops are connected to the same wireless network.

Comment: Please read [this guide](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/homegroup-help#homegroup-start-to-finish=windows-7&v1h=win81tab1&v2h=win7tab1) and see if that helps you understand what you need to do. 
If you still have questions after following the guide, please explain where you are having problems.

Comment: yes I have read this guide, the problem is with adding another computer to the created homegroup. When I open the other computer homegroup, it doesn't appear any : "join now" as appears on the guide.

Comment: On both PC's, click start button, then right click on "Computer" and choose "properties", near the bottom of the windows that appears, check that the "Workgroup:" settings display the same name. If not, click on "Change settings" and make them the same, then reboot and try again.

Answer (score 1):

A homegroup is not like a domain. You just have a textfield and if its the exact same name as on another pc, they are in the same group.

So change it and type it in exactly as it appears on the other computer and reboot when the computer tells you to do so, and it will show up as if both pc's are in the same group.